# Как убрать из html блок при определённом размере экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок с большими картинками, которые на мобильном вообще не нужны.
Если скрывать через `@media .nomob{display:none}`, то картинки всё равно жрут трафик.

Я так понимаю, что тут поможет JS-скрипт со сравнением размера экрана:

```
      function screen_check(){
            if ($(window).width() <= 992) { 
               $('.nomob').?????????;
            } ;
        }
screen_check();
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    screen_check();
});
```

Пожалуйста, без jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше определять устройство на сервере по `User-Agent:` в `Headers`. 
И в зависимости от устройства посылать мобильную или десктопную версию. Тогда не потребуется грузить `front-end` лишними скриптами.

Comment: Да, я как раз нашёл похожее решение.
https://github.com/aktuba/MobileDetector/blob/master/MobileDetector.php
Должно помочь.

Comment: Тогда отмечайте  правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Поведение тут будет зависеть от браузера, в большестве браузеров изображения скрытые `display: none` предварительно загружаются, так же как и с указанием `media query` (как в  CSS-файле, так и в `<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: Xpx)...`). Единственный сценарий в котором не происходит загрузка изображение: [это скрытый родительский элемент, где у потомков изображения установлены фоном](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/). Так что если вы хотите обойтись средствами CSS — замените изображения блоками с фоном.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант: Можно воспользоваться элементом [`<picture>`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/237991/), но он пока [поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture) не всеми браузерами.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/w3zakcr1/) для границы в 1024 точек ширины области отображения:

css: скрываем `div` с изображением

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
    #n2 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

html: в `source` медиа-запрос показывает большое изображение при ширине области отображения в 1025 точек и больше, иначе идет показ маленького изображения (превью) из `img`, которое не видно из-за `css` правила.

```
<div id="n1">
    <img src="http://jpegshare.net/thumbs/fc/39/fc390b2cebab53f54a4d41e5145a7322.jpg">
</div>
<div id="n2">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 1025px)" srcset="http://jpegshare.net/images/fc/39/fc390b2cebab53f54a4d41e5145a7322.png">
      <img src="http://jpegshare.net/thumbs/fc/39/fc390b2cebab53f54a4d41e5145a7322.jpg">
    </picture>
</div>
```

P.S. В браузерах не поддерживающих `<picture>`, будут показаны только превью.

Comment: `<picture>` вместе с `srcset` - это бальзам на души фронтедщиков.